# Redirecting the output of svnadmin dump to another server

Tags: linux, svn, io-redirection

I currently have a SVN repository on a server that is low in available disk space. I thus would like to migrate this SVN repository to a new server. Usually I would use the following command:

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/somerepository > somerepository.svn.backup
```

However, as mentioned above, I am very low on disk space and I would like to store the dump of my new server by streaming the `stdout` of the `svnadmin dump` process to the new server. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a couple of netcat commands to "stream" the dump away:

old server: start netcat in server mode, piped to svnadmin

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/somerepository | nc -q 10 -l -p 6666
```

new server: connect to other netcat instance and save stream on file

```
nc -w 10 oldserver 6666 > somerepository.svn.backup
```

Comment: netcat! Yeah, that was the program I was looking for. Let me test that before accepting the answer :)